# Get count of folder files and store into ArrayList

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a Folder (like C:/myfolders/Unprocecced) in that it has two subfolders(like LS, LT) and each subfolder contains some files. Now i want to  count each folder files count store in an ArrayList.
Give me an idea please.

Comment: If you're using C# 4, why do you want to use non-generic collections? Anyway, look at `Directory.GetFiles` - then after you've tried for a while, if you still have a problem, include your code in the question along with what's going wrong.

Comment: I probably should have waited until he/she tried doing something for themselves. Apologies...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Dictionary` of the sub-directories and there file counts as follows

```
Dictionary<string, int> fileCountDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\SomeDirectory");
foreach (DirectoryInfo tmpDi in di.EnumerateDirectories())
    fileCountDict.Add(tmpDi.FullName, tmpDi.GetFiles().Count());
```

I hope this helps.